# AppOpsManager.noteOp: How can I configure my app to crash on specific op

Tags: android, android-app-ops

In [AppOpsManager.noteOp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager#noteOp(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), it said `SecurityException` will be thrown

> if the app has been configured to crash on this op

I can't find any information about how to do that. Is it something app developer can configure in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.
It's already explained in the document of [AppOpsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager)

> To control access the app-op can be set to a mode to:
>
> MODE_ERRORED
> Throw a SecurityException on access. This can be suppressed by using a ...noThrow method to check the mode

To set MODE_ERRORED, you can use adb shell command: `cmd appops set <package> <OP> deny`